# How re-render react when toggle properties change

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react-webpart

I'm using spfx and react, i have toggle on WebPart properties, and i want to re redner when toggle was change in the .Ts page not in Tsx, i have no idea how to do this, there is no SetState on .ts.
I want when toggle is changed, List get the other list (bascule with ListA and ListB)

```
public render(): void {

    const element: React.ReactElement<IFaqProps > = React.createElement(
      a,
      {
        List : this.this.properties.checkToggle==true? this.ListA : this.ListB


        }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

  }



protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {

      return {
        pages: [
          {
            header: {
              description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
            },
            groups: [
              {
                groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
                groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: 'description'
                }),

                PropertyPaneToggle('checkToggle', {
                label : "Toggle",
               checked : false,
               onText : "Yes",
               offText: "NO"

      })
              ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom onPropertyPaneFieldChanged to re-render webpart.

Sample code.

```
protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
    if (propertyPath === 'listName' && newValue) {
      // push new list value
      super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
      // refresh the item selector control by repainting the property pane
      this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
      // re-render the web part as clearing the loading indicator removes the web part body
      this.render();      
    }
    else {
      super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, oldValue);
    }
  }
```